# django generating model choices dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

## models.py

```
class Make(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    #category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    make = models.ManyToManyField(Make)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

makes = Make.objects.all()
MAKE_CHOICES = [(str(cat.name),str(cat.name)) for cat in makes]
categories = Category.objects.all()
CAT_CHOICES = [(str(cat.name),str(cat.name)) for cat in categories]
subcategories = Subcategory.objects.all()
SUB_CHOICES = [(str(cat.name),str(cat.name)) for cat in subcategories]
class Subscription(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length = 40,choices = MAKE_CHOICES)
    #category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    category = models.CharField(max_length = 40,choices = CAT_CHOICES)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length = 40,choices = SUB_CHOICES)
    #subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(Subcategory)
    fixer = models.ForeignKey(Fixer)
    subscribed_on = models.DateTimeField()
    expires_on = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

## doubt

when subscription fields are displayed or prompted i need them to generate dynamically ,
as in if a category is selected then the subcategory field should only display all the subcategories related to that particular field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter ForeignKeyFeild Choices in field by value in other field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400458/filter-foreignkeyfeild-choices-in-field-by-value-in-other-field)

Comment: i understand that its not possible via django to dynamically change the fields ,but is it possible to render the form and then dynamically ad choices to one of its fields such as on selection of a particular category it should create a new subcategory select box with the suitable subcategories.